# How to track BluetoothAdapter state changes dynamically in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-bluetooth

In my app, I would like to know if a user enables/disables Bluetooth using the status bar and display a relevant piece of UI. For that, I think that I need to keep track of the current `BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled` status in my `@Composable` functions. This is what I have:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter by lazy {
        val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        bluetoothManager.adapter
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        var isBluetoothEnabled = bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled

        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                MainScreen(isBluetoothEnabled)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MainScreen(
    isBluetoothEnabled: Boolean
) {
    if (isBluetoothEnabled) {
        // Display some UI
    } else {
        // Display different UI
    }
}
```

When the app is launched, I can get the correct status of Bluetooth for the app, but since `BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled` is not part of the `@Composable` lifecycle, I'm not able to track it afterwards and react to changes like it's a piece of reactive state. Is there any way to achieve the behavior that I want here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this just by using `mutableStateOf`. It doesn't have to be initialized inside of a `@Composable` function to be reactive, which is what I misunderstood in the first place.

1. Define a `mutableStateOf` value and a `BroadcastReceiver` that will track the state of `BluetoothAdapter`. When Bluetooth state changes, update the value.

```kotlin
    private var isBluetoothEnabled = mutableStateOf(false)

    private val mReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            if (intent?.action == BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED) {
                when (intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR)) {
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF -> {
                        isBluetoothEnabled.value = false
                        Log.i("Bluetooth", "State OFF")
                    }
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON -> {
                        isBluetoothEnabled.value = true
                        Log.i("Bluetooth", "State ON")
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

2. Inside of a `@Composable` function, use this value as usual:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun MainScreen(
    isBluetoothEnabled: MutableState<Boolean>
) {
    if (isBluetoothEnabled) {
        // Display some UI
    } else {
        // Display different UI
    }
}
```

And that's it!

Comment: you actually don't need live data here, it would work fine with `var isBluetoothEnabled by mutableStateOf(false)`

Comment: I guess my broader question here is how would you make compose functions react to changes in non-compose functions without using some observable pattern?

Comment: Bluetooth state has to live outside of compose "world" (but that's only my assumption), so I need to connect it to my compose functions and react to updates in UI. So if you just initialize it as a  `mutableStateOf()`, how would you update it later? Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: Compose reacts to changes to `mutableStateOf` no matter where it is stored

Comment: You're right! I cannot thank you enough. I've completely misunderstood what `mutableStateOf` is. Even though it's integrated in the compose runtime, it doesn't have be to initialized within it. It just creates an observable that can then be tracked by `@Composable` functions.

I've edited my answer in case someone else gets confused by this.